# How to reserve space for Snakemake jobs?

Tags: memory-management, snakemake

I now and then run into problems (linux/ubuntu) because the job started by Snakemake runs out of memory due to other processes I have no control over. Execution can die pretty ungracefully.

I could check for available memory through `onstart:`, or even before I run a command, but that is clunky and not even safe.

Programs like [plink](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/) seem to be able to reserve space - is there a way to do this in (or for) Snakemake? I use the `run:` directive, so I'm backed by python ...

Comment: Snakemake itself doesn't support this. You could take a look at [resources](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources), but you will keep the problem that you can not correct for other people's behaviour.

Comment: See if this Q&A on biostars.org helps https://www.biostars.org/p/424706/#424810

Comment: [resources](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources) is really nice, but it is the opposite of what I seek: It lets _my_ jobs behave setting a max. I'd like to set a minimum :-)